# How to find the docker name/hash so that it can be exported?

Tags: ubuntu, docker, container

I've build a docker container from a dockerscript, e.g.

```
user@servername:~$ echo "FROM ubuntu:latest" > dscript.txt
user@servername:~$ 
user@servername:~$ cat dscript.txt 
FROM ubuntu:latest
user@servername:~$ docker build -t ubu.image - < dscript.txt
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/1 : FROM ubuntu:latest
 ---> 0ef2e08ed3fa
Successfully built 0ef2e08ed3fa
```

And I can run it by using the image name I've given, i.e. `ubu.image`:

```
user@servername:~$ docker run -it ubu.image
root@c00379445b9d:/# exit
exit
user@servername:~$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
user@servername:~$ sudo docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
```

But to export it I have to use the commit hash:

```
user@servername:~$ docker export c00379445b9d > ubu.image.tar
```

I've tried using the container name instead of the hash but it throws an error:

```
$ docker export ubu.image > ubu.image.tar
Error response from daemon: No such container: ubu.image
```

The question is:

1. Is there a way to find out the latest commit hash of the container that's needed to export the container as a `.tar` file?
2. Without the latest commit hash, is it possible to export the container as `.tar` file? Is so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ubu.image` you used is image name, not container name, so you can't use it in argument to `docker export`.

If you know the container name, then you can use it directly to export:

```
docker export <container name>
```

or getting its hash:

```
docker ps -aqf 'name=<container name>'
```

Without container name, you can get all list of containers with the given image name:

```
docker ps -aqf 'ancestor=<image name>'
```

Beware that it will return all containers built from the given image.

---

A better approach, is setting your own container `label`, so that you can use it to filter the container:

```
$ docker run -l foo=bar alpine sh -c 'echo 1'
1
$ docker run -l foo=baz alpine sh -c 'echo 1'
1
$ docker ps -aqf 'label=foo=bar'
d43aa7d7c854
```

Comment: To get the container name, do I need to first commit the image and the push to docker hub?

Comment: Ah the label trick is good =)

Comment: Hmmm, the `--label` trick didn't work on `docker build`. Does `docker ps -aqf` work when you use `docker build` instead of `docker run`? It returned nothing for me =(

Comment: @alvas you misunderstood the concept of `image` and `container`. `docker ps` only list and filter containers, it has nothing to do with image. You build the image, the run a container base on that image. The `docker export` is also container operation, not image.

Comment: AHHHH, okay now there's like tonnes of rubbish images I've created in `docker images`...

Comment: Other than doing it manually with `docker images`, can I find the image id given the image name?

Comment: @alvas you can filter image by label